# Remote Desktop Sharing Logs

Tags: windows-server-2008

Does Windows Remote Desktop Sharing generate a log of the machine which has taken control (the remote system's IP or something else I can use to identify it)?

If so, where would I find these logs?

Comment: ok its true I would have down voted this question also, but hey its this guys 1st question give him a little insight as to what he did wrong ok?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the proper auditing enabled, this information is stored in the Security portion of the Event Viewer.